# problem in defining custom 404 in docker nginx image of a html,css project

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-image, custom-error-pages

sorry for nob question.im not able to define a custom 404 in a docker nginx image for a html site,i tried adding a nginx.conf manualy but it didnt work

it works when run the project on nginx localy

here is my dockerfile:

```
FROM nginx:alpine
COPY . /usr/share/nginx/html
```